# Listen All Requests Tomcat

Tags: java, html, authentication, tomcat, authorization

I am using Tomcat with HTML files not jsp or anyting else. Every file is static(they uses JQuery) However when a user wants to navigate from my urls I want to check for authorization and don't want to show pages redirect them if not authorized.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible to do with just HTML, you need to make use of some server-side scripting to make the authorization and redirection,,

Otherwise,,
Try using `CGI Scripts(Common Gateway Interface)` in apache to authorize the requests,,

Also you can make use of `.htaccess` to authorize the users and deny the unauthorized requests,,

> A combination of both `.htaccess and CGI` can accomplish the work you
>   need to be done without the Server-side scripting,,